# dd from dvd to apfs on Catalina is writing very slow

Tags: command-line, catalina, apfs

I did

```
dd if=/dev/disk2 of="disk 1".iso bs=1m
```

where disk2 is a DVD video.  After about 30 minutes, `dd` spewed out the usual message of

```
7662+1 records in
7662+1 records out
8034680832 bytes transferred in 2007.685274 secs (4001962 bytes/sec)
```

but I didn't get my prompt back.  I checked (from another shell) and the image was 800+Meg and growing.  It is now 6.7G and still growing and I figure somewhere something has a ton of data stored.  Perhaps dd forks with one process reading and the other process writing with the data between the two going over a pipe.  But, this is new with Catalina.

Has anyone seen this before?  Is there a way to speed things up?  This is going to end up taking over an hour to copy one DVD.  This is on a laptop and the hard drive is an SSD.

Comment: Is this a movie DVD which may imploy some crazy copy protection scheme?

Comment: I don't think so.  It is from the History Channel, produced around 2000, and HandBrake, etc all seem to understand the iso images just fine.